# C++ add folder with files

Tags: c++, windows, exe

I have a very old and big project, which calls different EXE files during simulation. All of them are placed in one folder. For now, the folder directory was in the path env variable, but unfortunately I had to remove it from there.

Is there a way to add a folder to the list where process is searching for files? I know it could be done for DLLs by SetDllDirectory but this doesn't work for EXEs.

If this can't be done, is it possible to change working directory for thread (not for process)?

Comment: You can use `setlocal` to modify the PATH variable for the parent process only, make a small batch file with `setlocal`, `set PATH=whatever`, and then `myapp.exe`.

Comment: This would work but I can't do this ;/ (my app is called by a different one through DLLs)

Comment: Can you create a symlink with the old name pointing to the new directory, somewhere in a legit path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On starting of a new process (EXE), Windows creates a copy of the environment variables buffer of parent process for the started new process. All changes on environment variables of started process have therefore no effect on the environment variables of the parent process. In other words Windows makes a malloc + memcpy to create a new environment variables table for the started process.

So in your application you can use [GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188.aspx) to load the string value of local copy of **PATH**.

Next check if this string contains already the path of directory containing the EXEs to call (from a previous call of your application). Nothing to do if **PATH** contains already this path.

Otherwise check if **PATH** string ends already with a semi-colon. If this is not the case append a semi-colon. Then append the path of the directory containing the EXEs to call. Finally, update process copy of environment variable **PATH** by updated string using [SetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206.aspx).

Take a look on the [Changing Environment Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682009.aspx) example code.

Now with updating the **PATH** environment variable for your application (process) only, calling or starting the other executables should work.